# Solving forced wave equation by separation of variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If a system satisfies the equation
$$u_{tt} + u_t - u_{xx} = 0$$
subjected to conditions: $u(0,t)=u(2,t)=u(x,0)=0$, $u_t(t,0) = x$
how would I solve this? Separation of variables should work, and I can sove for $X_n(x) = \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{2})$ with $\lambda_n = \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{4}$ without any issues. But I don't know how to deal with the ODE that you get when solving for $T(t)$; it doesn't seem to simplify down to a trigonometric expression. I could leave it as a sum of exponentials but that seems extremely messy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge 1$ I get $$T_n(x) = e^{-t/2} \left(a_n \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}}{2} t\right) + b_n \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-1}}{2} t\right)\right)$$

which isn't all that messy.